# Uso da Função GREP

Tags: r, regex

Olá,

Tenho um arquivo .csv com o CEP no meio do endereço, entre colchetes. Em alguns casos não há cep, mas sempre existe o conjunto[], eventualmente vazio, por exemplo:

```
RUA ESTEVAM DE ARAÚJO DE ALMEIDA 521 L 17 Q. 15 [23028730] GUARATIBA
```

Quero esta informação em uma nova variável. Para isso, escrevi um código R para extrair o cep através da função `grep`, mas está gerando erro:

```
hans$cep <- grep("\\[*?\\d{8}\\]", hans$endereco.do.domicilio, value = T)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "cep", value = c("RUA ESTEVAM DE ARAÚJO DE ALMEIDA 521 L 17 Q. 15 [23028730] GUARATIBA",  : 
  replacement has 59940 rows, data has 61674
```

Comment: tenta usar a função `str_extract` do pacote `stringr`

Comment: O erro ocorre porque o `grep` retorna apenas os valores que encontra, em oposição ao `str_extract` que retorna `NA` quando não encontra nada. Por isso ocorre o erro dentro do  `data.frame` , já que há menos valores sendo retornados do que linhas no data.frame

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, tente utilizar o seguinte código

```
library(tidyverse)
hans <- hans  %>%
   mutate(CEP = str_extract(endereco.do.domicilio, "\\[*?\\d{8}\\]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa essa função.

`CEP=$(echo $endereco_completo | TR "\[" "\n" | grep ']' | cut -c1-8)`

Preste atenção nas aspas, pois pode dar erro se a do grep for " ou inverno de '.